# Ios/Android App Store Download Location Tracking

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics, google-play, app-store

Took a gander though the Android and IOS docs this morning and was trying to see if I can get anything closer than a territory/country for the download location.  I only want to track the users location at download for a campaign but am not sure that it is possible in either app store or with google analytics without also tracking them post install.  Does anyone have an idea if this is possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use clevertap.com for this...they have some pretty sleak campaigns models. And they raise location automatically based on ip / maxmind api

Answer (score 0):

you can see a cumulative count of downloads by country under the statistics section in google play developer console. change the date ranges and check the locations as you want.